# IF command query

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to calculate different percentages for the same cell. Let's say for arguments sake it's cell `A1`:

```
If A1 <   50000 then multiply by 10%  
If A1 >   50000 then multiply by 12.5%  
If A1 > 1000000 then multiply by 15%
```

I'm trying to use an IF formula but it won't let me put three conditions, just two.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to decide what to do if A1 = 50000 or if A1 = 1000000, but this should get you started.  Put this formula in cell B1 and copy it down:

=IF(A1>1000000,A1*0.15,IF(A1>50000,A1*0.125,IF(A1<50000,A1*0.1,)))

You can easily change the >  to a >=, depending on your decision.

Comment: You are welcome, Claire....Could you please "upvote" the answer (in addition to the checkmark?  :-)  )

Comment: Upvoting requires a reputation of 15

Answer (score 0):

First of all this IF(A1<50000;A1=A1/10) it is circular and will not work you can not change a cell from another shell unless you use VBA 
I asume that you need something like this

`=IF(A1<50000;A1*(10/100);IF(A1<=100000;A1*(15/100);A1*(12,5/100)))`

Comment: thank you - yes the above seems correct but it is giving me an error in excel?